# CMake doesn't find locally built Python

Tags: python, cmake

I'd like to include a locally built version of Python into a CMake project. However, I don't manage to point it to the right direction (at least not fully). Here is my stripped down CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Question)

set(PYTHON_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Python-3.6.10)
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Python-3.6.10/Include)

set(PYTHON_LIBRARIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Python-3.6.10)
set(PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Python-3.6.10/Include)

set(Python3_ROOT_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Python-3.6.10)
set(Python3_FIND_STRATEGY "LOCATION")
find_package(Python3 3.6 EXACT COMPONENTS Development REQUIRED)
```

I tried different combinations of the flags and variables given here. The closest I could get, was the error message

`Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS Development) (found suitable exact version "3.6")`

It seems to find Python but there is still something missing. Do I need to compile Python with special parameters? I didn't install the compiled Python with the altinstall script, because I don't see the point in it, when I just want to use it for one purpose.

I'm using CMake 3.16.3 - if I don't request an exact version, Python 3.8, that is installed on my system, is found without any problems.

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: I think the problem could be that you don't have the development package installed in your system (the package is called "python-devel") usually.Could you try to install it? Also, the reason why specifying "EXACT" make fail the CMake call could be that you have the development package for other Python version

Comment: The installed version of Python (3.8) is recognized correctly (including the development package) - my problem is rather, that CMake doesn't seem to find the correct files for a Python-version that I've built on my own in a sub-folder.